# How to pass Parameters from a region to other regions

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, prism, wpftoolkit

I need a suggestion how to pass Parameters(set of data which is selected) from region1 to region2 and region3 in same page
Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for some mechanism to pass data from one Viewmodel to another one, you can make use of either EventAggregator.

Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx

Or if you are looking for a simple mechanism, you can make use of Mediator pattern
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like using x:Name and binding it to the element name.
Small example.

```
<List x:Name="Data1">
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="Region2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Data1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
<ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="Region3" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Data1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```